# Events handled by another saga (Redux-Saga)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to create an error interceptor for all my sagas, after analyzing the redux-saga eventChannel I tried to create a saga like this:

```
export function interceptor() {
  return eventChannel(() => {
    api.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,

      (error) => {
        const { response } = error;

        if ([401, 403].includes(response.status)) {
            emit(AuthCreators.logoutRequest());
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    return () => null;
  });
}
```

In rootSaga it is being called this way:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    return yield all([fork(interceptor), anotherSaga, anotherSaga2]);
}
```

This way, every time one of my other sagas has a catch the interceptor is triggered, however my emit that should trigger the logoutRequest that is in other saga is not being triggered.

- How can the emit call other saga?
- Is this the best way to create an error interceptor?

Already grateful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand you question exactly but this might help you

```
const saga = [
anotherSaga, anotherSaga2
]

yield all(sagas.map((saga) => spawn(function* () {
        try {
            yield call(saga);
        } catch (e) {
            // console.log(e);
            // here we should store all errors in some service...
        }
    })));
```

Comment: I would like to create a function that any error that happens in any saga triggers it, that way I can handle some standard errors without having to repeat in every TRY/CATCH

Comment: well just try the above snippet, that should do the work for you